# How to send a custom app url scheme through MFMessageViewController

Tags: ios, url, sms

When I create a MFmessageViewController, I want to set the body of the text as the custom url scheme of my app, so the recipient of the text can open the app from the text. I can't get the text to appear as a URL though, only a string? Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *bodyString = @"<a href='http://www.site.co.in/pathtolink'>Touch Me</a>\n";
```

Set the bodyString as Email Body, hope it would help you.

Comment: Where does the custom url scheme fit into that url?